# write files on remote server using perl ssh

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, remote-access

i am trying to create files on different server using perl

is that possible ?

that what i have till now

I have tried this but it only write local

```
my $xml =qq|

hello

 |;

 open FILE,">","../hello/".$randchar . ".xml";print FILE $xml;close FILE;
```

this create a local XML file under folder hello

is it possible to create the XML file on different server ? and what are my option ? i am using Linux on both servers

for example using ssh
thanks

Comment: You say you are trying to use ssh, but I fail to see anything ssh-related in that code!

Comment: Tip: `scp` might be a bit more appropriate than `ssh`, and would work pretty much anywhere `ssh` works.

Comment: @ikegami thats it i do not know how to continue the code to achieve what i am looking for it, thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "continue"? You haven't started. You haven't even [looked](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=scp&mode=all) for a module or tried to use the command line tool. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like this:

```
echo text|ssh server "cat >file"
```

However I do not see why you use perl and what you want it to do.

Alternatively you might create the file locally and move it to the server using:

```
scp file server:
```

From within perl you might use something like:

```
system("scp", "file", "server:");
```

If you want to work on multiple files another alternative might be using [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). This allows you to mount a directory of the other server and work with it using local file access.

Comment: i am using perl cause the script that i am using is based perl.. i am trying to move these xml files that will be created to a different server